# Linaro Toolchain - ARM Executable

Tags: c++, arm, cross-platform, cross-compiling, remote-debugging

Good evening,

With many of http://releases.linaro.org arm build tools i've come acquainted to using this compiler for my cross platform environments.

The problem that I seem to be having is that upon attempting to remote debug from either a 64-bit linux or windows machine the arm GDB provided by Linaro's releases seem to crash on windows or everytime I attempt to step through my code the error received is:
Remote reply 'g' packet too long...

Keep in mind that all my libraries are built with the same compiler **LinaroGCC-4.9-2015.05** and are built statically into my Executable.
I used to be able to debug with an older version and have retried every single one available on linaros site and have not suceeded..

Please note that I have never attempted to build a compiler because of fright. I believe that the problem is quite low level and have never adventured far beyond this...

The project works flawlessly as long as I run it, but if ever I need to add new features there would be absolutely NO way that I could debug.

If there's any logs I can provide you with in order for you to understand my problem better... let me know. I'm calling for help now because i've been struggling on this for over 3 and a half months...

Thanks again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone searching for a partial solution to this problem its quite vague but simple. My solution was simply using the newest Linaro toolchain with an older linaro toolchain debugger.

The last working version compatible with Windows 10 was: arm-linux-gnueabihf-c++.exe (crosstool-NG linaro-1.13.1-4.9-2014.09 - Linaro GCC 4.9-2014.09) 4.9.2 20140904 (prerelease) With this GDB and the newest compiler everything seems to work seemlessly on Windows 10 64-bit. Please note: The host used for this GDB is: i586 and not i686.